# Timeout for String.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the width and height attribute to the  tag via javascript. The img src will be from the web (http://www.....). I am using javascript.replace to add in the height and width. Here is my code. (currently its just for width).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {

        var htmlString = '<div class="sample"> <img src="https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-5.jpg"> </div><div class="sample_another"><img src="http://www.crazymonkeydefense.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sample-img3.png"> </div> ';

        function dostuff(img, imgString) {
            img.onload = function() {

                imgString = imgString.replace("<img ", '<img width="' + this.width + 'px" ');
                console.log("modified = " + imgString);
            };
        }

        var modifyImg = function(imgString) {
            console.log("original = " + imgString)

            if (imgString.indexOf('width="') == -1) {
                var newImgString = (imgString.substring(imgString.lastIndexOf('src="'), imgString.lastIndexOf('"'))).replace('src="', '');
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = newImgString;
                dostuff(img, imgString);
            }
            return imgString;
        }

        modifiedHtmlString = htmlString.replace(/<img[^>]+>/g, modifyImg);
        console.log(modifiedHtmlString);


    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

the problem with this is that htmlString.replace(/]+>/g, modifyImg) this performs instantly and sets the ModifyImg value to be undefined rather then getting it from the return statement.

How do I approach this solution.

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function, you have to do the replace **inside** the `onload` handler, or any function called inside it etc. A timeout is not the correct fix.

Comment: ... And why don't you use .setAttribute() instead of a regex?

Comment: @adeneo Can you explain me on how to approach this? 
Btw i do want to run this function on load

Comment: @baao i have a string and not DOM so cant use that

Comment: This has more issues than just the problems with asynchrony. `modifyImg` does absolutely nothing to the string (remember that you can't modify strings *in-place* you need to return new values!) so it's quite weird that it's used with a `string.replace` call. This is not a we-code-your-program service but if you tell us what you are trying to do, maybe someone can point you to the right direction.

Comment: Of course you can, simply create the element. You don’t need to attach it to the DOM, but you can create it.

Comment: @noppa 
If i hardcode the width instead of fetching it, it does work. but beacuse it takes time to get it, the replace just sets it to undefined. 

I am trying this and this is where i ended up. 

My end goal is input will be a HTML string .
Output will be to add the width and height attribute to the img tag

Comment: @baao 
Sometimes the string might have script tag as well. </script> tag creates a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Using `done()` function may help you resolve this.

```
$.when(ModifyImg).done(function(v){
  modifiedHtmlString =  htmlString.replace(/<img[^>]+>/g,v);
  console.log(modifiedHtmlString);
});
```

Comment: tried it, still the same result it does not update :(